# Jquery validate multiple inputs with email

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I have a form where i ask the user to input email addresses  for an automated email to be sent. I have set both the email inputs to be required and to check for valid email, but it seems to work only for the first one. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 <form class="validate" method="post" id="formLoc">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="email-from">from</label>
            <input type="text"   class="required email" id="email-from" placeholder="from" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="email-to">to</label>
            <input type="text" id="email-to" class="required email"  placeholder="to" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="email-message">message</label>
            <textarea id="email-message" cols="100" rows="40"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="email-sent">
            <h4></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="SendEmailButton">
            <button type="submit" data-role="button" data-icon="forward" data-inline="true"
                data-mini="true" data-theme="c">send</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Here's a fiddle with the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/bobby5193/8dHg9/544/

Comment: It works for me also for the second email field...

Comment: you checked the fiddle and it works? I'm checking in Chrome and it only triggers for the first one. Could it be browser related?

Comment: the thing is, it will show the error on focus for the second input, but even if i leave it blank, the form is validated.

Comment: Consider using [the `type="email"` and `required` attributes](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) on your input elements in addition to your approach, especially since you're making a mobile site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `name` attribute to both input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="email-from" class="required email" id="email-from" placeholder="from" />
<input type="text" name="email-to" id="email-to" class="required email" placeholder="to" />
<textarea name="email-message" id="email-message" cols="100" rows="40" class="required"></textarea>
```

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VDkmK/)

**Update**

Here is an updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmarsh123/vFeNy/1/)** which has validation on the `textarea`. I added the `name` attribute and `class="required"` to it.

Comment: So if he omits the `name` attribute, the validation code somehow thinks both fields have the same (empty) name and only checks one of them?

Comment: @Blazemonger That is exactly how I have always looked at it, but I don't want to say yes or no as I do not know the exact reason. I ran into this same problem a while back and happened to figure it out so it just stuck with me. I'm sorry I can't give you an answer, I would like to know as well.

Comment: Incidentally, his textarea needs a `name` attribute too, at least if he wants to process the form server-side.

Comment: @Blazemonger yes, you are correct, and I should have included that from the beginning. I updated the answer with it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get more than one text box to insert Email like

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input id="emailcheck" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="ToEmails[0]" required />
    <input id="emailcheck" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="ToEmails[1]" required />
    <input id="emailcheck" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="ToEmails[2]" required />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now we will get all email address from text box.

```
var email = $('input[name^=ToEmails]');  
console.log(email);
```